error installing latest version of appmap-node
i'm trying to run
npx appmap-node pnpm start 
after that it asks
Need to install the following packages: appmap-node@2.24.2
and this is the error that i face
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c76987c9a3c183fa\\node_modules\\appmap-node',

npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c76987c9a3c183fa\node_modules\appmap-node\dist\util'] {

npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c76987c9a3c183fa\\node_modules\\appmap-node\\dist\\util'

npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]

i've already tried
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm@latest --force
but it didn't help

The error was on appmap's side and seems to be fixed now it's working as intended

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
